# PDE plotting assistance needed

Tags: numerical-integration

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
pdeset = {Derivative[1, 0][U][t, x] == Derivative[0, 2][U][t, x], 
Derivative[1, 0][T][t, x] == Derivative[0, 2][T][t, x] + E Derivative[0, 1][U][t, x]^2}
ics = {U[0, x] == 0, T[0, x] == 0};
bcs = {U[t, 0] == cos[t], T[t, 0] == 1, U[t, 10] == 0, T[t, 10] == 0 };
bcAll = Flatten[{ics, bcs}, 1];
```

- For `E=0.1`, when I try to solve

  `sol = NDSolve[{pdeset, bcAll}, {U, T}, {t, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 4 Pi}]`

I get this error NDSolve::bcedge: "Boundary condition U[t,10]==0 is not specified on a single edge of the boundary of the computational domain"

- **How to plot `Derivative[0, 1][T][t, x] as x->0 vs t (0...Pi)` for `E=0.1,0.2,0.3`?**

Comment: You asked a question, accepted an answer, then modified the question and unaccepted the answer. How many times do you plan to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fixing the `Cos` typo and making a bold decision that  the xrange ends at `4 Pi` not `10`

```
 ClearAll["Global`*"];
 pdeset = {Derivative[1, 0][U][t, x] == Derivative[0, 2][U][t, x], 
 Derivative[1, 0][T][t, x] == 
 Derivative[0, 2][T][t, x] + E Derivative[0, 1][U][t, x]^2}
 ics = {U[0, x] == 0, T[0, x] == 0};
 bcs = {U[t, 0] == Cos[t], U[t, 4 Pi] == 0,T[t, 0] == 1, T[t, 4 Pi] == 0};
 bcAll = Flatten[{ics, bcs}, 1];
 sol = NDSolve[{pdeset, bcAll}, {U, T}, {t, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 4 Pi}];
```

> (* NDSolve::ibcinc: Warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent. *)

The warning is because you have specified both `U` and `T` to be simultaneously `0` and `1` at the origin.  You get a solution but it obviously doesn't satisfy both conditions.

```
 Plot3D[ (T /. First@sol)[t, x] , {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {t, 0, 5}, 
      PlotRange -> All]
```

this figure shows but `U` and `T` with red lines indicating the prescribed boundary conditions.

[image]

here is your plot:

```
 Plot[Evaluate[  (D[(T /. First@sol)[t, x], x]) /. x -> 0 ], {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After correcting some syntax errors and setting consistent boundary conditions:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
e = 0.1;
pdeset =
 {Derivative[1, 0][U][t, x] == Derivative[0, 2][U][t, x], 
  Derivative[1, 0][T][t, x] == Derivative[0, 2][T][t, x] + e Derivative[0, 1][U][t, x]^2}
ics =
  {U[0, x] == 0,
   T[0, x] == 0};
bcs =
  {U[t, 0] == Sin[t],
   T[t, 0] == 0,
   U[t, 10] == 0,
   T[t, 10] == 0};
bcAll = Flatten[{ics, bcs}, 1];

sol = NDSolve[{pdeset, bcAll}, {U, T}, {t, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 10}]

VectorPlot[{U[t, x], T[t, x]} /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 10}, 
 VectorScale -> {Small, Scaled[.5], None}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thx dear but why change bc `T[t,0]=1` and how plot `Derivative[0, 1][T][t, x] as x->0 vs t (0...Pi)` for `e=0.1,0.2,0.3`?

Comment: @MMM The ics and the bcs should be coherent

Comment: Dear @belisarius, I am still hoping to learn how to plot Derivative[0, 1][T][t, x] as x->0 vs t (0...Pi) for e=0.1,0.2,0.3?

Comment: i am still waiting for your @belisarius response?